# Alternative Javascript library for wipein & wipeout functionality of Dojo

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, dojo, requirejs

Dojo library has this wonderful way of disabling & enabling input elements inside a div tag. It is called wipeControls and it needs dojo.js to function. Is there is any alternative library which functions without dojo?

To give a perspective, I am converting an existing humongous form which has been prototyped using dojo to a functional form with backbone.js and require.js

Comment: Why can't you use dojo itself for the functional form?

Comment: After using the uncompressed dojo, the error seems to be this 
NS_ERROR_FAILURE
xhr.send(null);